# flutter_webview_plugin how to listen on url changed for javascript

Tags: flutter

I'm using flutter_webview_plugin
I need to listen on url changed. 
I found when the url changed for javascript, the method 'onUrlChanged.listen' is not working.
Could anybody help me to solve this problem?

[Here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGXx0.png)

Answer (score 0):

make your widget StatefulWidget
and in initState() method 
do the following

```
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
       flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
      if(url.contains("#"))
        print("your data");

    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But i found my real question is about javascript. The method 'onUrlChanged' is not working for url change for javascript.

Comment: you can listen to javascript script changes

Comment: Thank you, but i don't know how to listen to. Would you please show me how to do that?